# How to evaluate $\int \frac{x dx}{x^4 + 6x^2 + 5}$?

Tags: indefinite-integrals

$$\int \frac{x dx}{x^4 + 6x^2 + 5}$$

How to evaluate this integral ?

Comment: What did you try? Why didn't it work?

Comment: @RSerrao ,  Cofactor resolution, something like what haqnatural did, right after reduce it to cofactor and grouping them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int  \frac { xdx }{ x^{ 4 }+6x^{ 2 }+5 } =\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \int { \frac { d{ x }^{ 2 } }{ { \left( { x }^{ 2 }+3 \right)  }^{ 2 }-4 }  } =\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \left[ \int { \frac { d{ x }^{ 2 } }{ \left( { x }^{ 2 }+1 \right) \left( { x }^{ 2 }+5 \right)  }  }  \right] =\frac { 1 }{ 8 } \left[ \int { \frac { d{ x }^{ 2 } }{ \left( { x }^{ 2 }+1 \right)  } -\int { \frac { d{ x }^{ 2 } }{ \left( { x }^{ 2 }+5 \right)  }  }  }  \right] =\\ =\frac { 1 }{ 8 } \left[ \int { \frac { d\left( { x }^{ 2 }+1 \right)  }{ \left( { x }^{ 2 }+1 \right)  } -\int { \frac { d\left( { x }^{ 2 }+5 \right)  }{ \left( { x }^{ 2 }+5 \right)  }  }  }  \right] =\frac { 1 }{ 8 } \ln { \left| \frac { { x }^{ 2 }+1 }{ { x }^{ 2 }+5 }  \right|  } +C$$

Comment: Hi, why $dx^2$ ? Is it cofactor resolution or just simple variable change ?

Comment: Hi @Edilson,i just put $x $ under differential,you can also substitute $x^2$ with another variable and solve it

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $$x^4+6x^2+5=(x^2+1)(x^2+5)$$ And then make $u=x^2$.